# Scala convert string to enum with values

Tags: scala, enums

I started learning scala and I have little problem. I want to convert string value into Enum but occur error `No value found for "TEST"`. What mistake did I?

```
object Function1 extends Enumeration {
    val TEST = Value("1")
    val TES = Value("2")
    val TE = Value("3")
  }
 println(Function1 withName "TEST")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the **name** of `Enumeration`, the **name** in `Enumeration` actually is the `Value`'s parameter, for your example should be **1**

> /** Creates a fresh value, part of this enumeration, called `name`.
>
> @param name A human-readable name for that value.
>
> @return  Fresh value called `name`.
>
> Value(name: String): Value = Value(nextId, name)

and for `withName` definition:

> Return a `Value` from this `Enumeration` whose name matches the
>   argument `s`.  The names are determined automatically via reflection.

Comment: Thanks for answer, is it possible to create enum with function like in java?

Comment: You can use `trait` with `case object` to simulate Java's `enum`

Answer (score 4):

You should use one of the followings:

```
println(Function1.TEST)
```

or

```
println(Function1.withName("1"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought its work a little difference. Is it possible to create function to each enum like in java?